# Toggle divs based on checkbox selection in dialog

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

New to Javascript, I'm struggling with some basic challenges: I want to toggle divs based on the selection of corresponding checkboxes. Those checkboxes are placed in a dialog and the selection should be applied after clicking a save button. I could just find examples that toggle divs right away when selecting the corresponding checkbox.

HTML:

```
<button id="filterDialog">Select DIVs</button>
<div id="filters" title="filters">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="filters" value="div01">div01</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="filters" value="div02">div02</label>
</div>
<div id="div01"></div>
<div id="div02"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() { 
        checkState = [];
        var buttons = {
                Cancel: cancel,
                Save: save
        };

        $('#filterDialog').click(function() { $('#filters').dialog('open'); });

        $('#filters').dialog({ 
                autoOpen: false, 
                modal: true,
                buttons: buttons,
                open: openDialog
        });
});

function openDialog() {
    $(':checkbox', this).each(function() {
        $(this).prop('original', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
}

function select() {
        $(':checkbox', this).prop('checked', true);
}

function deselect() {
        $(':checkbox', this).prop('checked', false);
}

function save() {
        // what to implement, so that divs are displayed accordingly to checkboxes?
        $(this).dialog('close');
}

function cancel() {
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
            $(this).prop('checked', $(this).prop('original'));
        });
        $(this).dialog('close');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rhdNH/86/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
function save() {
    // what to implement, so that divs are displayed accordingly to checkboxes?

  $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val()
    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true)
    {
        $('#' + val).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#' + val).hide();
    }
});

    $(this).dialog('close');
}
```

Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhdNH/114/). I noticed that you were using the type of checkbox as the selector in that case you might want to remove the double quotes in your cancel function.